# Simplifying Simultaneous equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing an 8th grade math text book, and came across this problem:

$4a +  $ $ 5b +  $ $9c$ = 36; and 7a + 9b + 17c = 66, what is a + b + c = ?

The first thing I could notice was that, " How could you find a suitable solution for two equations with THREE variables "
But still hoped that there must be some way to solve it.

If I've forgotten any basic concept, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4a+ 5b +9c = 36$;

$7a + 9b + 17c = 66$;

$\implies$ (multiply $1$st equation by $2$)

$8a+ 10b +18c = 72$;

$7a + 9b + 17c = 66$;

Then subtract equations:

$a+b+c= (8a+10b+18c) - (7a+9b+17c) = ...$ .

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped. But why do you need to multiply by two only? or is it because 2 is SUITABLE for THIS problem? please explain

Comment: Yes, it is suitable for THIS problem. Here you need to note that coefficients are almost proportional.

Comment: I got it right. Thankyou again.

Comment: If you have $2$ equations with $3$ variables, and you need to write something like $a+b+c$, in most cases it must be something like $K_1*LHS_1+K_2*LHS_2$. Here $K_1=2, K_2=-1$. (LHS - "left-hand side of equation")

Comment: You are welcome :) I am happy that so young person is user of MathStackexchange.

Comment: My father introduced this site for me to ask questions (because I'm home schooled), and he also said that, don't only ask, also help others. But when I browsed the unanswered questions, most of them were of a higher standard. So thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$$36x+66y=x(4a+5b+9c)+y(7a+9b+17c)$$
$$36x+66y=a(4x+7y)+b(5x+9y)+c(9x+17y)\ \ \  \ (1)$$

So we need to choose  $x,y$ such that $$4x+7y=5x+9y=9x+17y=1$$

Solving $\displaystyle 4x+7y=1\ \ \ \ (2),5x+9y=1\ \ \ \ (3)$ for $x,y$ we get $x=2,y=-1$ which satisfies $9x+17y=1\  \ \ \ (4)$

Set the values of $x,y$ in $(1)$

Comment: For what are the x, and y there

Comment: @Ramana, Please find the edited version

Comment: I cannot find it :( help

Comment: @Ramana, Please pinpoint your area of confusion

Comment: Why should we bring in the variables x,y here to solve these two equations?

Comment: @Ramana, to identify the multipliers

Answer (score 0):

Use the two equations and solve them for $b$ and $c$ considering that $a$ is a constant (these are two linear equations for two unknowns). You should arrive to $$b=\frac{9}{2}-\frac{5 a}{4}$$ $$c=\frac{a}{4}+\frac{3}{2}$$ I am sure that you can take from her.